# Backend database used in the API

Tags: api, zomato-api, database, nosql

By going through this API documentation page, is it possible to tell which database is being used in the backend?

[Zomato API](https://www.zomato.com/api/documentation)

MySQL would require a php file on the server to handle the requests, make queries, pack data in JSON format then send it back to the device. But in this case parameters are passed to `.json` files. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "see through" to what the backend service actually used to provide you with the information you may query for.  Are you sure you want to continue using this product? The site notes that `Zomato` will no longer be available to individuals, and that your API key will be disabled if you don't use it monthly.

Comment: Actually I'm not using the api itself. I've created an app which is similar to it in a way and I'm currently using REST to pass parameters to a php file stored on the server which in turn queries the MySQL database, packs the results to JSON and returns it to the client. I wanted to know about this api's database as I figured it would reduce the load on the server caused due to the long search queries. 
If its not possible to find the backend database used by them, can you tell me if the approach i'm using right now is good or possibly the best possible one?

Comment: So I guess my answer that there is no way to see what backend process (and database if that is how they store their data) suffices ... or do you have a different question?

Comment: I guess it does. I will mark it as the answer, but could you please check my edit to the previous comment and provide your insight on it?

Comment: Then is your question about how to choose the "right" database engine and how to design the database structure for high perfomance when access by many programs concurrently?  If so, that question might be better asked in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Its just used by my android app to search and provide appropriate results. Yes, I'm in a dilemma as to whether using PHP+MySQL is the best database approach for me and I really want to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the specs for that particular API. But in general, is it possible to tell what database is being used on the back end by studying an API? No. That's the whole point of an API: It's supposed to shield the API-user from implementation details.

It's probably true that in many cases you could make reasonable guesses about what tools are being used on the back end. Like if you see that the API gives you a syntax for doing comparisons that looks exactly like the proprietary compare function used in Foobar SQL and not found in any other database product, that would be a strong clue. But even something like that wouldn't be proof. Maybe originally they were using Foobar SQL, then they switched to another database, but to maintain compatibility they wrote code to translate the Foobar SQL compare to standard SQL syntax.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you very much. I will look up more about this. Any chance you could please give me an answer for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512402/online-database-recommendation-accessed-by-android-app
Its the reason i'm trying to figure this out